# Unable to mark directory as Test Sources in Pycharm for javascript

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, pycharm

I have installed `node.js` and `nodeunit` on my computer. Now I am following the instructions from `JetBrains` on creating unit tests here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/unit-testing-node-js.html:

[image]

Specifically this step: `Mark the _tests_ as a "test directory"` : that option is not available for some reason from the right click/context menu:

[image]

What is missing so that that option would be available?

Comment: This option is not available in PyCharm, please follow instructions without it, everything should work as expected, the doc has been updated.

Comment: @user2235698  Where is the doc updated?  Also  pls make an answer and I'll award

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available in PyCharm.

Please follow instructions without it, everything should work as expected.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/unit-testing-node-js.html has been updated.